# Express JS - download file

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am working on ExpressJS application(let's call it App A) and use axios to make requests to another ExpressJS app(let's call it App B) endpoints.
The related endpoint in App B is tested and it is confirmed it responds with proper pdf file - tested with Postman.
I want in App A to download a pdf file given as a response from App B.
What is the proper way to do it?

Here is related piece of code:

```
  const FormData = require("form-data");

  let responsePdf = null;
  const fieldsJSON = JSON.stringify(fields);
  const mustraFileP = mustraUpFoldPathGet(mustraFileName);

  const apiUrl = documentToolApiUrlGet("template", "docx-template-pdf");
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(FILE_UP_NAME, fs.createReadStream(mustraFileP));
  formData.append("fields", fieldsJSON);
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, formData, {
      headers: {
        ...formData.getHeaders(),
      },
    });

    responsePdf = response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err", err);
  }
  // TODO: download file using responsePdf
```

I tried several ways but seems none of these are working as expected:

- Tried to convert response to blob and then use blob to make file from it but didn't succeed.
- Tried with http module using on event but didn't manage to save file properly.